# Github - Git CLI: How to clone all repositories in directory

Tags: git, github, github-cli

I can individually clone using "gh repo clone reponame".

and list them using "gh repo list ORGNAME"

But how do I automatically clone all of them in the list

thanks

gh repo clone reponame

gh repo list ORGNAME

Comment: `gh repo list ORGNAME | while read repo; do git repo clone "$repo"; done`

Comment: I think it is too late to adjust _but_ I think it is `git clone`, not `git repo clone`, just in case.

Comment: Well, it's `gh repo clone`, in this case 

Answer (score 2):

You can try this command `gh-repo-clone-all`.

Documentation - > https://www.npmjs.com/package/gh-repo-clone-all